# extern template class std::vector<FwdDecld>;

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have a class containing a `std::vector<FwdDecl>` member. I'd like to do

```
extern template class std::vector<FwdDecld>;
```

in the header and

```
template class std::vector<FwdDecld>;
```

in the `.cpp` so my class's special member functions can be automatic (rather than declaring all six in the `.h` and `=default`ing all six in the `.cpp`).

It seems that this works with MSVC and Apple Clang, but not Clang or GCC:
https://godbolt.org/z/Tc8G91rj6

This works just fine with `boost::container::vector`, though: https://godbolt.org/z/j6zfj4K3r

Is this correct? Are GCC and Clang being compliant? Is MSVC?

Related `extern template class std::unique_ptr<FwdDecl>` does seem to work (although obviously it's not copyable), even when the forward-declared class is private: https://godbolt.org/z/ThhW4fPGE

Comment: It is only libstdc++ that has a problem with this. (Add `-stdlib=libc++` to Clang.)

Comment: Ah, thanks, https://godbolt.org/z/Yx6vWf45v
Any idea if it's a defect in GCC or if GCC is compliant? Being able to do `extern template class` like this would be nice.

Comment: I guess this depends on whether or not the enumeration of members required for https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#explicit-10 counts as referencing a member in the sense of https://eel.is/c++draft/vector#overview-4.sentence-2, but I am not sure that there is not a more general issue with this.

Comment: Related [LWG issue 2303](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2303), but which is about the explicit instantiation definition with the completed type, rather than the declaration with incomplete type.

Comment: Maybe just to clarify: Do you really want the class to be and remain incomplete in the header file? Because that seems to be the only concern here. If the definition of the custom type was reachable from the explicit instantiation declaration, only the issue I linked above remains. And I don't know what purpose the explicit instantiation declaration on an incomplete element type is supposed to serve.

Comment: @user17732522 the use case that brought me here is basically wanting to have class `C` have a `std::vector<FwdDecl>` member similar to the PImpl idiom, but the member is a `std::vector`. I can explicitly declare the six special member functions `C(); ~C(); C(const C&); C(C&&) noexcept;` and the two `operator=`s, and then in the `.cpp` do `C::C() = default; C::~C() = default; ...` but I was hoping that by just doing `extern template class std::vector<FwdDecl>;` in the header and `template class std::vector<fwdDecl>;` in the source I could avoid the boilerplate.